# nginx reverse proxy for xnxx.com

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Hi how to do reverse proxy in ***nginx*** for website like ***www.xnxx.com*** and served all data inside web page like videos and image through reversed proxy. my config so far but through me to **error 502 Bad Gateway**

```
server {
listen 80;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
       server_name *.xnxx.works xnxx.works;
       location / {
        proxy_pass https://www.xnxx.com/;
        proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        sub_filter 'https://xnxx.com' '';
        sub_filter_once off;
       }
}
```